# How was the world running after Kamadev's death?

Tags: shiva, kamadeva, parvati

Tarkasur had a boon by Lord Shiva that he could be killed only by Shiva's son. Devtas assigned Kamadeva to stop Lord Shiva's meditation and create love in his heart, so that as a result Shiva's son can be born.

Kamadeva and Rati were played their role to create love between Lord Shiva & Parvati, but when Lord Shiva come to know about this, he got angry and opened his third eye. A fire raised from his third eye which burned the Kamadev.

On request of Kamadeva's wife Rati, Lord Shiva gave her a boon that in Dvapara Yuga, Kamadeva will re-born as Shree Krishna's son named *Pradyumnna*.

Now without the Kamadeva, it is not possible for a new life to born. So the question is How the new life was being created between the time period of the death and the re-born of kamadeva?

Comment: There was no creation. This is the time period when bhanDAsura raged and made the universe bereft of all creation/creativity. Then the dEvas sought refuge in sadAziva who performed the yAga from which lalita tripurasundari emerged, destroyed bhanDAsura and restored life to manmatha.

Answer (score 5):

Shiva's third eye did not kill Kama, it merely rendered him Ananga or bodiless; [here](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/bala/sarga23/bala_23_frame.htm) is how Vishwamitra describes to Rama and Lakshmana in the Bala Kanda of the Ramayana:

> When Love-god was with his body wise men used to call him Kama, the passion. At this place, that Love-god with his naughty intent braved god of gods Shiva who had been practising ascesis and who concentrated observantly, and who was returning after his marriage along with his followers, namely the Wind-gods, and that great soul Shiva disapprovingly roared at Love-god.  And Rama, the wrathful third-eye of Shiva destroyed the lewd-minded Love-god making all his limbs to fall down from his body.  There the body of Love-god is evanesced when that great soul Shiva burnt it down, and by the anger of that god of gods Shiva, Love-god is rendered as a bodiless entity.  Then onwards Love-god is renowned as Ananga, as he is without body, and where his body is given up that is renowned as Anga province.

So Kama's soul was still around to cause people to fall in love and have children and the like.

Comment: You should remove the word "Shiva" from your answer because the sanskrit verses never use "Shiva". The verses of Valmiki Ramayana in the link you gave uses "devesham", "rudrena", "deva Ishvara" but not "Shiva".

Comment: I do not make any distinction at all between Shiva and Rudra; as a Sri Vaishnava I consider Brahma and Shiva to be Jivas.

Comment: That is your personal opinion, scriptures say that Shiva and Rudra are different. Let's for a second believe that Shiva and Rudra are one, still we can't post Shiva because Sage Valmiki himself didn't use "Shiva".

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria That would be like saying we can't post Vishnu because Valmiki used Narayana rather than Vishnu.

Comment: I'm not sure if scriptures say Vishnu is same as Narayana but scriptures definitely don't say that Shiva is Rudra.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, here's two examples off the top of my head.  In the Srimad Bhagavatam, when Rudra is born, Brahma gives him many names including Rudra and Shiva.  And in the Taittiriya Samhita of the Yajur Veda, for which the Devata is listed as Rudra, Shiva is given as one of the names.

Comment: @Keshav There is also the thing that the Maruts accompany **Indra** rather than Shiva so it is unclear why Valmiki portrays them with Shiva. It is also unclear why Shiva is "just married" in this verse when actually Manmatha Dahana was before his marriage. I think there is a question about this verse on thus site.

Comment: @Surya The terms "Maruts" and "Rudras" are used pretty much interchangeably in the Vedas.  Western Indologists speculate that there was originally one group of storm gods referred to as both the Maruts and Rudras, and then later they separated into two concepts, the notion of storm gods who are attendants of Indra and storm gods who are attendants of Shiva.

Comment: @Keshav Why do you follow Western Indologists? They do not know anything. Plus how do you explain Shiva already being married?

Comment: @Surya Yeah, I don't agree with Western Indologists on this issue, I was just pointing what their speculation is.  In any case, when Valmiki says Maruts, he's talking about the Rudras here.  As to Shiva being married, I'm not sure how to explain that.  This is admittedly far-fetched, but I suppose it could be talking about Shiva's marriage with Sati.  It could be saying that after he had married Sati and she died, he was struck by Kama.  Or it could just be a case of interpolation or Kalpa Bheda.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41665/discussion-on-answer-by-keshav-srinivasan-how-was-the-world-running-after-kamade).